# Unable to download in google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, windows-10

I am running windows 10 and google chrome  52.0.2743.116 m

I can download files using Firefox to my Desktop and Downloads directory but I can't in google chrome.

If I am using google drive I get the message "Failed - Forbidden". If go to an html page and try to save an image I get "Failed - Insufficient Permission".

The output of 
    cacls Download

is as follows

> C:\Users\jjs\Downloads jjs-asus\jjs:F 
>                         jjs-asus\None:(special access:)
>
> ```
>                                 READ_CONTROL
>                                 SYNCHRONIZE
>                                 FILE_GENERIC_WRITE
>                                 FILE_GENERIC_EXECUTE
>                                 FILE_WRITE_DATA
>                                 FILE_APPEND_DATA
>                                 FILE_WRITE_EA
>                                 FILE_EXECUTE
>                                 FILE_DELETE_CHILD
>                                 FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES
>                                 FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES
>
>                   Everyone:(special access:)
>
>                            READ_CONTROL
>                            SYNCHRONIZE
>                            FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES
>
>                   NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(OI)(CI)(special access:)
>
>                                               READ_CONTROL
>                                               SYNCHRONIZE
>                                               FILE_GENERIC_WRITE
>                                               FILE_GENERIC_EXECUTE
>                                               FILE_WRITE_DATA
>                                               FILE_APPEND_DATA
>                                               FILE_WRITE_EA
>                                               FILE_EXECUTE
>                                               FILE_DELETE_CHILD
>                                               FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES
>                                               FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES
>
>                   BUILTIN\Administrators:(OI)(CI)(special access:)
>
>                                                  READ_CONTROL
>                                                  SYNCHRONIZE
>                                                  FILE_GENERIC_WRITE
>                                                  FILE_GENERIC_EXECUTE
>                                                  FILE_WRITE_DATA
>                                                  FILE_APPEND_DATA
>                                                  FILE_WRITE_EA
>                                                  FILE_EXECUTE
>                                                  FILE_DELETE_CHILD
>                                                  FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES
>                                                  FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES
>
>                   jjs-asus\jjs:(OI)(CI)(IO)(special access:)
>
>                                            READ_CONTROL
>                                            SYNCHRONIZE
>                                            FILE_GENERIC_WRITE
>                                            FILE_GENERIC_EXECUTE
>                                            FILE_WRITE_DATA
>                                            FILE_APPEND_DATA
>                                            FILE_WRITE_EA
>                                            FILE_EXECUTE
>                                            FILE_DELETE_CHILD
>                                            FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES
>                                            FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES
>
>                   jjs-asus\jjs:(OI)(CI)(IO)(special access:)
>
>                                            READ_CONTROL
>                                            SYNCHRONIZE
>                                            FILE_GENERIC_WRITE
>                                            FILE_GENERIC_EXECUTE
>                                            FILE_WRITE_DATA
>                                            FILE_APPEND_DATA
>                                            FILE_WRITE_EA
>                                            FILE_EXECUTE
>                                            FILE_DELETE_CHILD
>                                            FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES
>                                            FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES
> ```

Nothing here helped, but maybe I missed something.

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2898334?p=ui_download_errors&hl=en&ctx=36&rd=1

Answer (score 1):

Work around:
Created a new folder in the drive (in my case D:\ChromeDownloads)
In Chrome Settings, Show advanced settings, Downloads
changed path to new folder D:\ChromeDownloads

Downloads work normally now in Chrome.

Note:
If changed back to the Windows 10 managed Downloads folder path Chrome downloads fail again.

No root cause determined yet...